# AJAX combobox adding new items without autopostback="true"

Tags: asp.net, ajax, combobox

Buenos nachos, to be brief, my question is: is it possible to allow users to add new items to a combobox at runtime without having the autopostback property set to true? I understand it needs to postback if a new item is added, but I do not want the box to postback if the user simply selects a different value!

The tag I currently have is below. Without having the `autopostback="true"`, the comboxbox doesn't allow the user to add new items to the box >_<' Any thoughts?

```
<ajx:ComboBox ID="cbCompany" runat="server" Width="226px" DropDownStyle="DropDown"
  OnItemInserted="addCompany" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend">
</ajx:ComboBox>
```

I know I could add a few more controls and do an easy workaround, just wondering if it is possible to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to round-trip to the server for each single change in well designed components, the client should be able to handle most situations except those when the server **must** validate the data immediately.

That anti-pattern of everything needs postback or using .NET's lazy version of ajax (when the server deals with the tiny bits like, for example, adding items to a combo) is not good at all and JavaScript is there to do those simple tasks.

I downloaded the source code for ajaxcontroltoolkit's ComboBox and unfortunatelly I does not provide a good JavaScript interface.

You could try disabling postback and using something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addItemToDumbComboBox(cb, text)
{
        /* Based upon Combobox.pre method initializeOptionList() */

        // create the new list item
        var child = document.createElement('li');
        child.innerHTML = text;
        cb.get_optionListControl().appendChild(liItem);

        // add the item to the internal collection
        var item = { text: text.trim(); };
        Array.add(cb._optionListItems, item);

        // style the ListItem with default skin
        cb.initializeOptionListItem(child);
}

addItemToDumbComboBox(document.getElementById("cbCompany"), "new item #1");
addItemToDumbComboBox(document.getElementById("cbCompany"), "new item #2");
addItemToDumbComboBox(document.getElementById("cbCompany"), "new item #3");
</script>
```

... and see what happens. Note I didn't actually test this code, it's just an example.

BTW, I recomend you to switch to a combobox implementation with a decent JavaScript interface.

Having the server do all the job is like buying a toaster and every breakfast mailing it to the factory, along with the 2 slices of bread, to have them do the toasting and return it to you with your toasts... it's that dumb, but don't blame yourself, that's a common ASP.NET anti-pattern.

Hope that helps, and god bless!

Comment: I tried to keep my question brief, sorry for the lacking info. But I need it to post back to the server. The combo is initially populated with company names from a DB. But if the user's company isn't listed, they can enter a new one into the box which triggers my "OnItemInserted" event, which adds the item to the database and reloads the combobox. I just don't want it to postback when the user selects a different pre-existing value. Say they first go to the page, select a value that's already there, and it will postback :(

Comment: Well, crap, perhaps I can just do it your way, but add a __doPostBack()! Imma try it out..

Comment: I see, and I missed the OnItemInserted event. Let's see if I can be of any help... =)

Comment: The __doPostBack() could work. But, I was thinking... if you are using a textbox with a button to add a new company then you can disable cbCompany's autopostback and the button should still postback normally while selecting an existing company wouldn't.

Comment: without autopostback set to true, I can't even insert new items. If I set OnItemInserted="AddItemToDumbComboBox", it would never fire because I can't even do it. Do you think you could show an example of how the combobox would call your jscript function?

Comment: Lol, that's what I did as a workaround (added a "Add" button next to the combo), but thats what I wanted to avoid: Using extra controls. +1 btw for your help, I appreciate it

Comment: Oh! Now I get it you just wanted to have the combo and to have it automatically insert new items by typing directly, sorry for my lack of insight, I always supposed you had the button somewhere! lol As a sidenote, AddItemToDumbComboBox should be called by a javascript event, I thought it to be used on the previously non-existent Add button client-side onclick event =)

Comment: Ah! I knew there were client and server side events >_< I was getting frustrated cuz some events were looking at my code-behind, and some were looking for the javascript, and I didn't know why! I really need to learn more jscript... seems like this just can't be done. I'm going to leave the question unanswered in case someone stumbles here with a solution XD thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Disable `autopostback` for the combobox and try placing something like the folling code near the end of your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function subclassComboBox(cb)
{
    cb._old__onTextBoxBlur = cb._onTextBoxBlur;
    cb._onTextBoxBlur = function(e) {
        var saveAutoPostBack = cb.get_autoPostBack();
        cb.set_autoPostBack(false);

        cb._old_textBoxBlurHandler(e); 

        if (cb.get_selectedIndex() == -2) {
            /* -2 means that a custom value was typed. only in this case do postback */
            cb._doingPostBack = true;
            __doPostBack(cb.get_element().id, '');
        }

        cb.set_autoPostBack(saveAutoPostBack);
    };
    cb._old_textBoxBlurHandler = cb._textBoxBlurHandler;
    cb._textBoxBlurHandler = Function.createDelegate(cb, cb._onTextBoxBlur);

    $clearHandlers(cb.get_textBoxControl());
    $addHandlers(cb.get_textBoxControl(),
    {
        "click": cb._textBoxClickHandler,
        "focus": cb._textBoxFocusHandler,
        "blur": cb._textBoxBlurHandler,
        "keypress": cb._textBoxKeyPressHandler
    }, cb);
}

subclassComboBox(document.getElementById("cbCompany"));
</script>
```

I haven't tested this code, but the idea is to make the combo do a postback only when a new value is entered (even if autopostback is false). If this works you'll no longer need that button ;)